# Can't access local file via local webpage hyperlink

Tags: html, hyperlink, special-characters, local

I'm having some trouble linking to a file on the network via a local webpage. I've written a simple html page with a hyperlink:

```
<a href="h:\myfiles\dir#1\file1.s">View File</a>
```

Now what happens is when I click the link, I get an error message that windows cannot find the file specified. The file does exist but the link to the file that is displayed by the error message is not right.

I have:
`h:\myfiles\dir#1\file1.s`

Error Message:
`h:\myfiles\dir#1/file1.s` - All slashes after '#' are flipped.

I tried it again, but this time I removed the '#' from the directory name and fixed the hyperlink accordingly as well (`<a href="h:\myfiles\dir1\file1.s">View File</a>`). When I did it this way it works. I guess what I'm asking is that is there a workaround for links to directory files that have a '#' in the URL?

I know '#' is a special character and is used for anchor bookmarks, but how do I get around this. I don't want to remove the '#' for all the directory names that I have. How do I link to a file in a directory that has a '#' in it's name?

Thank you!

Comment: for local file use local file protocol `file:///h:/myfiles/dir1/file1.s`

Comment: I have tired that, but error message shows: `Windows cannot find 'H:\myfiles\dir#1/file1.s'. Make sure you typed the name correctly and try again.` Notice the flipped slash after the '#'.

Answer (score 0):

The # sign can be encoded as "%23". You might remember "%20" appearing anytime you tried entering a URL with a space in it (before browsers started switching to search anytime it didn't fit URL patterns)

Comment: I've tried this as well. The 'open', 'save', 'cancel' message appears, and then when I click open the same error message pops up.